Circuit hot only when connecting to ceiling mount light
I am not sure if I understand this circuit.

I have a ceiling light that has 4 wires, 2 are bundled together to make a pair.
There are two wires coming into it because it's connecting to another light.
Two black wires tight together to a pair from the light. Then two white wires tight together to another pair.


Here is what I don't understand:

If I undo the wire nuts and use a simple volt tester like this, and I touch any two pairs of white/black, there is no power.


Only when they are all tight up into the light, then there is power.


Question:

Why is that?
If I want to replace with a recessed light, what to do?


Can you post a picture from the other side to see how the wires are connected?  And a picture how the switch is wired.  You should have an always hot or a switched hot there.  Can you test the insulated wires to the ground?

Looking at the neutral on the right (further back), the insulation seems brittle?

You have a very simple circuit.
There are two cables in the box. They bring 2 black (switched hot in/ switched hot out), 2 white (neutrals) and 2 grounds (bare copper) into the box.
All grounds (bare copper) are tied together in the box. (The light fixture ground would be tied to these.)
One black is a switched hot from the wall switch. It transfers power to the other black wire that goes to the second light and provides power to the black wires from the first light fixture.  (There are 2 black wires from the fixture because there are 2 light bulbs.)
One white provides a path back to the breaker box. It is tied to the other white for the second light and the 2 white wires from the light fixture, ( this completes the circuit)
All the black wires should be tied together.  All white wires should be tied together.
If there is an issue of the light not working unless it is on the ceiling, the most likely cause is one, or both of the bundle of wires is not tied together properly.
Check that these wire bundles are tightly together. The wires should be all twisted together before a wire nut is put on them.
If all the wires are tightly bundled, and the problem persists, there could be a lost neutral from the cable coming into the box from the switch. The light may work when on the ceiling because the ground is completing the circuit. This would mean you need to check for where the neutral is lost.  The first place would be to check the white bundle in the switch box.  However I'm more convinced that the bundle of wires in those wire nuts is more likely the issue.
As to how to install a recessed light.  The direction for that would depend on the specific light and the manufacturers instructions.  However the cables in and out and the pairing of black and white wires would remain the same.
